# trying to loop an array thru linear search

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

this seems like it should be really basic but I'm having issues with it. I'm just starting out so please forgive me if this is answered in other posts - i wasn't able to find anything I know how to apply to my specific issue...I'm wanting to check for numbers 1-4 in an array then build a new array with true or false elements being results of the search...in JS

```js
function linearSearch(vector, x) {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (vector[i] == x) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function checkall() {
  var test = [2, 4, 1, 3];
  var collect = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var ck = linearSearch(test, i + 1);
    collect[i] = ck;
  }
  return collect;
}

console.log(checkall());
```

Comment: You need to use `var i` to make the variable local to each function. Otherwise, when you call `linearSearch` it changes the value of `i` in the `checkall()` loop.

Comment: Get in the habit of always declaring variables, unless you know you need a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare local variables, preferebly with `let` for using it in an own scope.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

If you take it as is, `i` is declared in global scope and it changes the behavior of the calling loop, as you can see of the below output.

```js
function linearSearch(vector, x) {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (vector[i] == x) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function checkall() {
  var test = [2, 4, 1, 3];
  var collect = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log('c0', i);               // should show
    var ck = linearSearch(test, i + 1);
    console.log('c1', i);               // same value
    collect[i] = ck;
  }
  return collect;
}

console.log(checkall());
```